# Como transformar um cv::Mat em ipcMatrix<ipcRGB>?

Tags: c++, opencv, cast

Alguém sabe se há uma forma fácil de transformar um `cv::Mat` em [`ipcMatrix<ipcRGB>`](http://www.uni-koblenz.de/~puma/dox-dev/puma/html/classipcMatrix.html)?

Comment: Bora traduzir o título da pergunta para português?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Com a ajuda do [@karlphillip](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/731/karlphillip) consegui **chegar em uma solução**:

```
cv::cvtColor(mat_input, mat_rgb, cv::COLOR_BGR2RGB);

int sz = mat_rgb.rows * mat_rgb.cols * mat_rgb.channels();
unsigned char* imageBuf = new unsigned char[sz];

memcpy(imageBuf,mat_rgb.data, sz);
ipcMatrix<ipcRGB> input = ipcMatrix<ipcRGB>(mat_rgb.cols, mat_rgb.rows, (ipcRGB*)imageBuf);
```

Dessa forma é possível transformar um `cv::Mat` em um `ipcMatrix<ipcRGB>`.